# Filtering random-outcomes from maplist/3 result

Tags: list, prolog, sicstus-prolog

I wish filter out this list `List=['F1',a1,a2,' LF2',a1,a2]` with predicate is_upper/2 and maplist/3  below

`is_upper(Elem,Res)` : if `Elem` is uppercase atom, it will be assigned to Res
then i'd like to put all uppercase atom into list `List_Upper`

i try this ;

```
?- maplist(is_upper,List,List_upper).
List_Upper = ['F1',_A,_B,'F2',_C,_D,'F3',_E,_F] ? ;
```

how I can filter the outs-random `_A,_B...`

**expcted Result :**

```
 List_Upper = ['F1','F2','F3']
```

regards

Comment: Check out the important meta-predicates `include/3`, `exclude/3` and  `partition/5`.

Comment: @mat: thx ,it's work with exclude/3 `exclude(is_upper,List,List,upper).`

Comment: @mat i observe that `SWI` is much easy to handle than `SICS`, but some of them have their benefits ; `SICS` much faster but greedy with `memory` whereas `SWI` less faster although stingy with `memory`, Can you advise me of which  `prolog tools` I used in my first step to learn `Prolog`? regards

Comment: In my view, SWI is indeed friendlier for beginners: It has `make/0`, a graphical tracer and lots of autoloading. All these features are fine for small programs and nice for beginners, but they tend to break in unexpected ways in more serious scenarios. I recommend you start with SWI-Prolog and then buy SICStus for serious work.

Comment: @mat,sorry,last qst :) prolog(`SWI`) have interface-design like `SICS(TCL)` ? and wheres the best and easy way to do this like `java(swing)` ? some tuto site

Comment: SWI has `XPCE`, but nowadays you typically go the web route and use SWI's `library(pengines)` and powerful web libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include/3` to collects elements of true resulte and `exclude/3` for the falses

```
| ?- include(is_lower,['FUNCTOR1','arg1','arg2','FUNCTOR2','arg3','arg4','FUNCTOR3','arg5','arg6'],List_Lower).
List_Lower = [arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6] ? ;
no
```